# Are files opened by File.ReadLine closed on exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, io

Is a file that is read through `File.ReadLines` closed if an exception is thrown while iterating over the resulting enumerable?

Example:

```
File.ReadLines("file.txt")
    .Select(line => { throw new Exception(); return 1; });
```

Is `file.txt` ever closed?

And if it is indeed closed, how can the fact that the iteration will not continue be determined by the implementation?

The reason why I can't understand how the file could be closed is the following. I suspect that the `ReadLines` implementation is something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string file)
{
    using (var reader <Open reader>)
    {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    } 
}
```

If an exception is thrown during the iteration all lines are not fetched from the resulting enumerator. Then line after the `while`-statement is never reached and the `using`-statement will not get a chance to close the stream.

Comment: Why wouldn't the file be closed? The using statement uses a finally so it's disposed regardless of the exception

Comment: But the while-loop only terminates when all lines have been read. This will not be the case unless the client actually finishes the iteration with the resulting enumerator. If an exception is thrown during iteration some elements are not fetched with the enumerator and the while-loop should not terminate.

Comment: You need to look at the implementation of `Select` to see why it gets closed.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how a `using` statements works. Or perhaps how `try...finally` works. A finally statement is **always** executed

Comment: @JamesBarrass: A finally-clause is always executed _when the flow of control leaves the try-clause_. If there is a non-terminating statement in the try-clause the finally-clause is not executed.

Comment: @Lii The while loop breaks when the exception is thrown so the flow of control leaves the try-clause when the exception is thrown, jumping straight to the finally clause. The exception doesn't cause an infinite loop

Comment: @JamesBarrass 1) That's an iterator, so the `finally` statement is quite different from a normal `finally` statement. The finally statement executes when the iterator reaches the end (never happens for the OP) or when the iterator is disposed. If disposing doesn't happen closing the file will be delayed to the iterator's finalizer, which may run much later if at all. 2) *always* is very strong, there are a bunch of cases, most of them involving forced process termination where they don't execute.

Comment: @JamesBarrass: _"while loop breaks when the exception is thrown"_ Hm. I think you are incorrect here and that the stream is closed by other means. See usr's answer.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, Yes, there are circumstances where finally statements aren't excecuted but I didn't think them relevant to the question, probably shouldn't have made it bold. 1) I'm intrigued so 'm to investigate this!

Comment: @JamesBarrass In the simple example of `File.ReadLines("file.txt").GetEnumerator()` the enumerator doesn't get `Dispose`d, so the file will will only be closed once finalizers run. Which may be *much* later, depending on the allocation behaviour of the process. The the question boils down to what (if anything) triggers the disposing of the enumerator and thus the filestream. This is a non trivial question which I got it wrong at first glance.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, obviously if you don't use a using statement or call Dispose explicitly then it's up to the finalizers. Or the OS if the process is closed first. I wouldn't say that's relevant either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an enumeration using a `foreach` is aborted the enumerator is disposed. C# iterator methods execute all active finally blocks in case of such an "early dispose". This means that all `using` statements inside of an iterator method are being honored because `using` is based on `finally`.

To make this more concrete: `Dispose` can only be called on a C# generated enumerator at a `yield return` statement. Only a `yield return` relinquishes control to the caller.

The generated state machine keeps track of what finally blocks are active at each yield point and executes them in the `Dispose` method.

If you simply abandon an enumerator (`File.ReadLines("file.txt").GetEnumerator();`) finally blocks are not honored. There is no mechanism to do that.

TL;DR: The file is being closed in all cases as long as you dispose the outermost enumerator and all enumerators in the chain (here: `Select` and `ReadLines`) properly dispose their inner enumerator using `finally`.

Comment: Ah, finally-blocks in the iteration methods that dispose the enumerators, that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: This really prompts for some caution when using one's own enumerable transversal methods to avoid leaving the file open.

Comment: @Lii if you use foreach or enclose all IEnumerator's in using it all works automatically. This is recommended anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see! Here is a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/23/iterator-blocks-part-five-push-vs-pull.aspx) on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will be closed. It internally creates a StreamReader over a FileStream and uses it inside a using block.
I'm not sure what you mean in the 2nd question (you could simply catch the exception).

Comment: I don't think this answer is very helpful, since the disposing of operators and thus the execution of the finally statements is triggered by code the OP didn't even post (the code that consumes the enumerator returned by calling `GetEnumerator()` on the result of the `Select`).